# Spring filter not run for root URL

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, servlet-filters

In the Spring config I have:

```
<beans:bean id="myFilter" class="foo.bar.MyFilter" />
<http>
  <custom-filter ref="myFilter" after="CHANNEL_FILTER"/>
```

I noticed, that when the root page is invoked with this URL : https://server/myApp then the filter is not run, while using https://server/myApp/  (only difference is the final slash) the filter is run. (it is also run for all sub-pages, like myApp/this , myApp/th/at)

Enabling DEBUG logging on `org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.DefaultFilterInvocationSecurityMetadataSource` I noticed that the `extractMatchingAttributes()` method does not even log anything.

The correct web page is displayed (the correct controller is run etc...) in both cases.

Why is that?

spring version is 3.0.x

**EDIT:**

This log gives a hint:

```
DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - Candidate is: ''; pattern is /**; matched=false
```

Comment: Apparently this is a limitation of spring 3.0.x where the filters get the match URL hardcoded to /** (so they expect a hash in all cases, while in the above case there will be no hash in the actual URL).

Comment: And by "hash" I mean "slash", of course.